# What is this scam? Card CVV entered incorrectly too many times

Tags: credit-card, scams, fraud, debit-card

I have a Visa debit card that I use mainly for travel (it has low FX fees).

The other day I received loads of notifications from the corresponding app: 2 with 'The CVV was incorrect', followed by 4 with 'The CVV was entered incorrectly too many times'. Most of these were for £0, one was for £1. The seemed to come from some pub in England in a town I had never been to. There was also one transaction right after in the US (for 0$, also declined), and another for 6$ in the US.

I have of course frozen the card right away, but I don't understand what the scammers were trying to do here. If they had cloned the card when I used it on my travels they would have had the correct CVV. Is this just some bulk attack where they try huge numbers of card numbers with random CVVs hoping to get some correct (given that CVVs are quite short?)?

Comment: I am not 100% sure of this but I don't believe the CVV is encoded on the barcode on the cards, so if they clone it using a swipe, it won't have the CVV so they would try to "guess" it so it can be associated with it and used, and like you said 3 digits the combinations are not that high so they might try and brute force it. That's just a guess.

Comment: I almost always used the card via Apple Pay. The card itself has almost never been used directly - maybe just to take cash out once. I wonder if card numbers may be also randomly sampled? Or would the attackers need to at least know the card number? An automated opportunistic attack seems more likely to me.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ There are two CVV. CVV1 is encoded in the magnetic stripe (there's no barcode on CCs). CVV2 is written on the card.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguous use of "barcode" but what I meant is the magnetic strip on the back, I believe most people got that.

Answer (score 14):

Given how low the transaction amounts were, they may have been trying to see whether the CVV was valid. If the first transaction goes through, then they would have tried a larger one.

> I have of course frozen the card right away, but I don't understand what the scammers were trying to do here. If they had cloned the card when I used it on my travels they would have had the correct CVV.

There are two CVVs. CVV1 is encoded in the magnetic stripe. CVV2 is written on the card. CVV1 is used for Card Present transactions, so presumably that would be the one used. In a swipe transaction, the CVV1 is read off the magnetic strip, and in a chip transaction the CVV1 is part of the encoded transaction data. So the leading hypothesis in my mind is that "CVV" is for some reason being used to refer to the PIN. I suppose that someone might have been trying to do a Card Not Present transaction, but that would be a weird thing to do. It is sometimes an option if something is wrong with the POS, but it's definitely discouraged.

> Is this just some bulk attack where they try huge numbers of card numbers with random CVVs hoping to get some correct (given that CVVs are quite short?)?

That's certainly a tactic used; if you can get a million credit card numbers, then having only 1/1000 CVV be correct still leaves you with a thousand valid CC. But that's more of an online tactic. It's not so practical at a physical location.

Comment: The transactions are not necessarily coming from a physical location, it could be some kind of attack on the pub's payment processing system, used specifically for testing CVVs without exposing who is doing it.

Comment: Do magnetic stripes still exist?

Comment: Very unlikely transactions were made from the physical locations - within a few seconds there were 5 transactions in the UK and 2 in the US.

Comment: @gerrit All my cards still have magnetic stripes. The US didn't adopt chips until 2015, and I suspect magnetic stripes will stick around for quite some time.

Comment: @MJD The US isn't the hold up. Japan, China, India, and Thailand didn't have their EMV liability shift until October 2017, a full 2 years after the US. It was not the US is behind, it was the Europeans shifted early due to higher telecom costs, fraud rates, laws allowing banks to deny liability for pin-authorized transactions, and the influence of their smart card industry.

Comment: @user71659 Don't forget Asia and CIS, which have been issuing chip cards nearly exclusively for a while. So it seems like the US *is* conservative - it even still has pre-digital payment methods like bank checks.

Comment: It's not 1 in 1000.  It's however many tries they get before triggering a lockout in 1000.

Comment: @Therac-PeaceforPalestine Uh, I just pointed out the big parts of Asia that didn't switch. And US checks are digital as far as the banking system is concerned. Here we have Europeans being snotty without looking how the rest of the world works. They're also going to be in denial when they find out the majority of cars in East Asia are automatics.

Comment: *"I suppose that someone might have been trying to do a Card Not Present transaction, but that would be a weird thing to do."* ─ Why would it be weird for a scammer to attempt a CNP transaction? It is much more likely than a scammer attempting an in-person transaction with a card they don't know the PIN for, as there is a lower chance of getting caught (pubs have CCTV). The fact it's a pub doesn't mean the scammer must attempt the charge in-person; lots of pubs allow ordering through apps, for example. And brute-force guessing a CVV (3 digits) is much easier than a PIN (4 digits).

Comment: @rinspy So when you say they were from a pub, you mean that the pub is listed as the merchant, not that they came from the physical location of the pub?

Answer (score 6):

The CVV is printed on the physical card. It isn't on the chip or the magnetic strip.

> seemed to come from some pub in England in a town I had never been to.

It is entered into the system when the card is not physically present. If you use the card at the pub, they don't need to enter the CVV. If it is being used online, or you are giving the number over the phone, the CVV is required. In your question the card number, expiration date and the CVV are being entered because the person is trying to purchase something online.

The credit card network is blocking the transaction because of too many wrong numbers being entered.

> Most of these were for £0, one was for £1.

I think the small transactions are pending transactions. This occurs typically at a gas station, or a restaurant but it could be almost any transaction. They place a hold for a small transaction until the transaction is finalized.

> 'The CVV was entered incorrectly too many times'

This means that the card is blocked. It could be permanently blocked, or it could become usable once a period of time has passed. If it was due to a typo, it would be nice to have it automatically unlock; but if was a fraud attempt it would be nice to keep it blocked.

Contact the card company to see what the next step is. They might give you a new number.

Comment: I have had restaurants/bars in the US ask me for the CVV on the card that I have handed them, so at least some establishments in some places are asking for the CVV even when the card is physically present. They can't read it because the numbers were printed, not embossed, and have worn off.

Comment: @shoover this makes no sense. If they're using the magnetic strip or the chip, the printed cvv should never be used.

Comment: "The CVV is printed on the physical card. It isn't on the chip or the magnetic strip." That is false. There are two CVV. CVV1 is encoded in the magnetic stripe. CVV2 is written on the card.

Comment: *I think the small transactions are pending transactions. This occurs typically at a gas station, or a restaurant but it could be almost any transaction. They place a hold for a small transaction until the transaction is finalized.* In my experience, the hold is for as high a transaction as could reasonably be expected - e.g., $100 (saw $200 recently!) for a tank of gas, because you don't know until the transaction is done how much it will be, but you want to make sure before a drop of gas is delivered that there will be money to pay for it.

Comment: My guess is they round the amount in the message, so £0 is any amount less than £1 and £1 is between £1  and £2. Small amounts to test validity - if it works then the next stop is a much more expensive store for something that can be resold (gift card, electronics, jewelry, etc.)

Comment: Small transactions are common when testing a stolen card to make sure it works before selling it

Comment: Don't think transactions were rounded - there is one in the US for $5.52, and then several in the UK for £0 and £1.

Comment: @shoover If they ask for a CVV they are using a device or contract which is designed for "card not present" transactions (phone or mail order). Using it when the customer is actually present is usually a breach of contract, they are required to use a device+contract designed for card present transactions, which will then use the chip (or, previously, the magnetic stripe). Asking for the CVV in such a setting makes them suspect.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Agreed - small $ transactions may also be used to test a user's awareness of their card statement. Slip through a few small transactions unnoticed, then start going larger.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon that makes little sense. If you are doing to perform the transaction yourself, making "warning shots" to see if the victim reacts has the risk of the victim becoming aware and blocking the card, and no benefits over directly maxing the card. That they are a different party trying to verify the data before forwarding the card to someone who can recover the money without leaving a trace.

Comment: *"If you use the card at the pub, they don't need to enter the CVV."* ─ That would have been true 20 years ago, but nowadays at many establishments, you can order using the pub's app. But the point you're making is correct; the scammer is attempting CNP (card not present) transactions.