# Why would I be asked for the last 4 digits of a card number for a card-present transaction?

Tags: credit-card, security

I regularly shop at a store where they ask me if I am a member of their loyalty program (no), then I insert my chip-enabled card into their card reader, the purchase is approved, and after the approval they ask me for the last 4 digits of the card number. Surely the POS system knows that, so why would they ask? They are OK with me holding up the card for them to read or telling them the 4 digits for them to type in.

Answer (score 3):

**This is a quick check to prevent the use of skimmed cards.**

This fraud occurs when a hardware [skimmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_fraud#Skimming) is used to secretly read the magnetic stripe from an ATM or point-of-sale terminal, or via a compromise in a store's POS system.

The quickest thing to do with skimmed data is to write it to another card and use it in a store. (The card data cannot be used online reliably, as the CVV2 isn't acquired. [They'd have to guess.](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/159506/what-is-this-scam-card-cvv-entered-incorrectly-too-many-times))

This check forces the fraudsters to create a reasonably looking card, per skimmed account, with proper embossed numbers. It would detect use of generic cards (e.g. hotel keys) or legitimate lost/stolen cards with the stripe re-written, as the last 4 digits between the magstripe and card would fail to match.

While sophisticated criminals could make reasonably-looking custom fake cards, this raises the bar above simply using a skimmer and a handheld card encoder.

This practice is largely obsolete, since EMV/Contactless replace the magnetic stripe. New cards, namely the Apple Card, have no numbers on the card, since a separate number is used for online use, and manually-keyed purchases are very rare.

There is one very limited scam it could protect against, which is when thieves intercept new cards in the mail, which are unactivated. They physically swap the chip with a fake one, and deliver it, the card is subsequently activated by the consumer (by calling or going online with secret information only known to the customer), and the stolen chip transplanted to a new card and used. This is a complex scheme requiring physical access and transplanting chips, so I'd think any organization pulling this off can easily replicate a fake card.

Comment: Sounds reasonable if they actually want to see the physical card. But OP mentions the merchant is perfectly fine with just being told the numbers, in which case they don't need to match what's embossed, defeating the entire purpose of this security check.

Comment: @TooTea The cashier should see the card, that's the employee being lazy or not properly trained. See [MasterCard Transaction Processing
Rules](https://www.mastercard.us/content/dam/mccom/en-us/documents/TPR-manual-June2015.pdf), page 68.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities, neither of which is a good reason.

First, their POS might not be fully integrated with the payment terminal and is unable to actually get the last four from the data that was read off your card.  So they ask you to provide it so that they can add it to the POS's record of the sale manually.  You could probably test this by swapping two digits in the last four and seeing whether your receipt shows the correct value (from the card) or your swapped value (from the POS).

The other possibility is that it's a simple fraud-prevention check, most likely left over from when cards were mostly swiped.  A fraudster won't *necessarily* know the last four of the card number on their fake card, especially if they took a real card and overwrote the magnetic strip with data read off of another card.  Someone really committed to the fraud could memorize it (or print it on the fake card), but it'd still likely catch a good number of the small percentage of people who tried this.  If this is the case, then the "swap two numbers" test above should have them prompt you to repeat it because it won't match what was actually read.  (Just correct yourself the second time and it should be fine.)

Either way, it indicates procedures or software that hasn't been keeping up, and should likely be revisited by the store management.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are asking for the last four digits, and allowing you to read them off, they aren't checking the signature. And if you aren't signing the receipt the signature check doesn't have anything to compare to.

I don't know what asking for the last 4 digits proves. You don't have to memorize it. It is something embossed/printed on the card. In many cases it is on both sides of the card.  The number is on the stripe and the chip.

When you save your card details on a website, they display some of the digits the next time you pay so that you will remember which card you have saved. There is no need to refresh your memory when you are using the physical card in a reader. Though printing it on the receipt does help, they already have all the info they need to print it.

It seems to me that this is a procedure the the store has them follow for all transactions even if it doesn't provide any benefit. It might have made sense in the past.